# "Cert authority invalid" error from Chrome on Android when viewing my website which uses Lets Encrypt

Tags: https, security-certificate, android, lets-encrypt

I have installed and activated open SSL (letsencrypt.org R3 version V3) on my website. Website is working fine in Desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox....) but in Google Chrome Android, I get security error. It seems not to be of previous cache because the error appeared today some days after installing SSL. Is there any issue with R2 and R3 SSL in Chrome mobile?

> YOUR CONNECTION IS NOT PRIVATE
>
> net err cert authority invalid

Comment: How old is your Android device?  As of September 30th when the old Lets Encrypt root certificate expired, Android 7.1.1 and earlier don't trust Lets Encrypt certificates.  https://techcrunch.com/2021/09/21/lets-encrypt-root-expiry/

Comment: Mine is Galaxy note 8. I have received Latest system update yesterday. But some iphone users also reported the same issue on our website. @StephenOstermiller

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_8 says it came with 7.1.1 but system updates take it to 9.0, so maybe that isn't the problem.   Especially if you are not having issues hitting other sites with Let's Encrypt certificates (including this one.)

Comment: What is your website?   Have you tried any tools to verify that your certificates are installed correctly?  I've used https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ in the past.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller [some Stack Exchange users were facing this issue though](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370443/241919). // Ali: make sure the certificate is using ISRG Root X1 as the root CA.

Comment: the website is zingapp.ir I could not solve the problem yet @StephenOstermiller

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.zingapp.ir says that you are serving the expired LetsEncrypt certificate chain.

Comment: Thanks. But the chain is working on other sites on this server. To care about other websites Do I need to remove the old chains and install new ones or installing new certificate chain is enough? @StephenOstermiller

Comment: I think that the new LetsEncrypt chain is signed by the old chain, so when you install the new LE chain, you end up with both.   You should install the chain the LetsEncrypt gives you when you get new certificates and you should not install other chains.